# Is there a canonical duplicate for `to_string` questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

These seem to have been popping up recently, in particular the latest is [g++ error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope. Tried adding -std=c++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936621/g-error-to-string-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-tried-adding-std-c0x). It seems that certain versions of GCC in Cygwin/MinGW ports don't support the [string conversion functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). This includes, `to_string`, `stod`, `stof`, etc. Another example of this question is [Cygwin not compiling stod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561919/cygwin-not-compiling-stod/26562330#26562330), which I answered:

> The short answer is that it's a bug within Cygwin's port of GCC (or
>   libstdc++). The only message I can find on the Cygwin mailing list is
>   from [Jan 29,
>   2014](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2014-01/msg00508.html) and it
>   merely says:
>
> > Did you try the suggestion for the same problem under mingw?  It looks
> >     like this could be a temporary workaround  until the problem is fixed.
> >     Just make
> >
> > sure you try it on
> >     /lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h if
> >     you're building for Cygwin..
>
> MinGW has been known to have issues with string conversion functions
>   as well, even though it's different from Cygwin. My suggestion is to
>   download Stephan T. Lavavej's [64-bit MinGW
>   distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) which comes with GCC 4.9.1
>   and many up to date packages.

Similarly, [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936621/g-error-to-string-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-tried-adding-std-c0x#comment42417647_26936621) links to this [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015#c15) which covers MinGW. Although MinGW and Cygwin are different, I'm certain that the both have related causes. Unfortunately since it's difficult to pinpoint the exact nature of this problem, I suspect similar questions will continue to pop up.

Is there a canonical duplicate for this problem? If not, what's the best way to handle this:

- Close as duplicates of previous answers (which I think can get messy)
- Answer it anyway, because it's difficult to locate duplicates

Comment: I've seen that also, the dupe may fit well.